# Signing Java String using Signature.sign: why is the signature is different every time?

Tags: java, sign

I have written a class that is meant to sign and base64 a string of text using a private key on the server and then return the signature. It is generating a different signature every time it is run for the same text. Why would it do that?
I have checked that it is the signature that is changing and not an issue with the base64 conversion by disabling the conversion temporarily on my test machine.

My code:

```
public class SigningPIP implements SigningPIPInterface {
private static final String SIGNING_ALGORITHM = "SHA1withDSA";

/**
 * Provides a signature for a stringified JSON license
 * @param license stringified JSON license to be used for signature generation
 * @param keystoreFilePath The file path where the keystore can be found
 * @param keystorePassword The password to the keystore
 * @param privateKeyAlias The alias of the private key in the keystore to be used for signing
 * @param privateKeyPassword The password for the private key to be used for signing
 * @return Properties object containing the base64 encoded signature, algorithm used and certificate DN
 */
@Override
public Properties getLicenseSignature(String license, String keystoreFilePath, String keystorePassword, String privateKeyAlias, String privateKeyPassword) {
    PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(keystoreFilePath, keystorePassword, privateKeyAlias, privateKeyPassword);

    Properties licenseSignature = new Properties();
    licenseSignature.setProperty("sig_algorithm", SIGNING_ALGORITHM);
    licenseSignature.setProperty("cert_DN", getCertificateIssuerDN(keystoreFilePath, keystorePassword, privateKeyAlias));

    byte[] licenseByteArray = license.getBytes();
    System.out.println(new String(licenseByteArray));
    try {
        Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance(SIGNING_ALGORITHM);
        dsa.initSign(privateKey);
        dsa.update(licenseByteArray);
        byte[] signature = dsa.sign();
        licenseSignature.setProperty("signature_base64", DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(signature));
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | SignatureException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        //TODO: Add logging
    }
    return licenseSignature;
}

/**
 * Pulls the private key from the specified keystore
 * @param keystoreFilePath The file path where the keystore can be found
 * @param keystorePassword The password to the keystore
 * @param privateKeyAlias The alias of the private key in the keystore
 * @param privateKeyPassword The password for the private key in the keystore
 * @return The specified private key from the keystore
 */
private PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String keystoreFilePath, String keystorePassword, String privateKeyAlias, String privateKeyPassword) {
    try {
        FileInputStream keyStoreFile = new FileInputStream(keystoreFilePath);
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(keyStoreFile, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
        return (PrivateKey)keyStore.getKey(privateKeyAlias, privateKeyPassword.toCharArray());
    }
    catch(KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        //TODO: Add logging;
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Pulls the Issuer DN from a keystore for the specified private key
 * @param keystoreFilePath The file path where the keystore can be found
 * @param keystorePassword The password to the keystore
 * @param privateKeyAlias The alias of the private key in the keystore
 * @return The Issuer DN for the private key
 */
private String getCertificateIssuerDN(String keystoreFilePath, String keystorePassword, String privateKeyAlias) {
    try {
        FileInputStream keyStoreFile = new FileInputStream(keystoreFilePath);
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(keyStoreFile, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)keyStore.getCertificate(privateKeyAlias);
        return certificate.getIssuerDN().getName();
    } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyStoreException e) {
        //TODO: Add logging
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) I'm guessing it's because it implements  RFC 6979,

> This ensures that k is different for each H(m) and unpredictable for attackers who do not know the private key x.

This is to prevent attacks on the secret key.